# Cant get .not() to work

Tags: jquery

Im having problems with jQuery. What i want to do is fadeIn all contents of a class but not a class of the div. Hard to explain, so i'll show a example.

This is the code:

```
$(".box").contents().hide();
$(".box").contents().fadeIn( 800, function () {
    $(".box .progress").delay(600).animate({width: 'toggle'}, 800);
});
```

and what I want to do is not fadeIn `$(".box .progress");` like this:

```
$(".box").contents().not(".box .progress").fadeIn(800, function () {
    $(".box .progress").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 800);
});
```

But this doesn't work, why?

Let me know if you want me to provide a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, provide a fiddle and the HTML in your question.

Comment: You're already dealing with the contents of `.box`, so there's no reason to specify `.box .progress` -- just `.progress` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when doing `$(".box").contents().not(".box .progress")`, you are removing element that match `.box .box .progress`. Only use .progress class :

```
$(".box").contents().not(".progress")
```

Comment: Aha okey! I get it! Thanks!